# Переинициализировать таблицу Datatebles при её обновлении

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, table

У меня есть таблица
        [image: datatable].
Не подскажете, как при нажатии на Save сделать так, чтобы страница обновлялась?
Используется Datatables.net. Пробовал юзать Destroy перед загрузкой данных - но ничего не происходило по итогу.

```css
function loadPosts(tableId, onSuccess) {
  $.ajax( {
    url: "/api/post/getfiltered", method: "POST", data: JSON.stringify( {}
    ), contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", success: function (result) {
      if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#'+tableId)) {
        $('#'+tableId).dataTable().destroy();
      }
      $('#' + tableId).dataTable( {
        data: preparePostsTableData(result.data), columns: [ {
          searchable: false
        }
        , null, {
          render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
            return new Date(data).toLocaleString()
          }
        }
        , null, null, {
          render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
            return formatStatus(data);
          }
        }
        , {
          visible: false
        }
        , {
          className: 'no-wrap', orderable: false, render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
            return formatActions(data.id, data.blockReason, data.shortText, data.tags);
          }
        }
        ]
      }
      );
    }
  }
  )
}

function editPost(id, shortText, tags) {
  $('#modal')[0].style.display='block';
  $('#pstText').val(shortText);
  $('#pstTags').val(tags);
  $('#idText').val(id);
}

function saveChange() {
  var id=$('#idText').val();
  var shortText=$('#pstText').val();
  var tags=$('#pstTags').val();
  $.ajax( {
    url: "/api/post/", method: "PUT", contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", data: JSON.stringify( {
      id: id, shortText: shortText, tags: tags
    }
    ), success: function (result) {
      $('#tblUsers').dataTable( {
        data: preparePostsTableData(result.data)
      }
      );
    }
  }
  ) $('#modal')[0].style.display='none';
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  loadPosts("tblPosts", function () {}
  );
}

);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tblPosts" data-order='[[ 1, "asc" ]]' data-page-length='25'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Author</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Text</th>
      <th>Tags</th>
      <th data-class-name="priority">Status</th>
      <th>isActive</th>
      <th data-formatter="formAction">Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Author</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Text</th>
      <th>Tags</th>
      <th data-class-name="priority">Status</th>
      <th>isActive</th>
      <th data-formatter="formAction">Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>

<div id="modal">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="visible">
    <h2>Edit</h2>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="form-group" style="display:none;">
        <label for="idText">Id:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="idText">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pstText">Text:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pstText">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pstTags">Tags:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pstTags">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="controlElems">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btnSave" onclick="saveChange()"> Save <i class="fa fa-save" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btnClose" onClick="closeChanges()">Close <i class="fa fa-close" aria-hidden="true"></i> </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

Comment: Где у вас объявление элемента таблицы типа DataTables в js, покажите код пожалуйста. Cтрока такого вида у вас есть в js: `var new_dt = $('...').DataTable({` ?

Comment: Минутку, сделаю правку

Comment: @RifmaMan поправил код - посмотрите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При инициализации таблицы вы должны занести ее в переменную `let my_dt = $('#' + tableId).dataTable({`, тогда, после отправки запроса на сохранение данных вы сможете обратиться к таблице и обновить ее - `my_dt.ajax.reload(null, false);`